# SQL Query query matching columns and counting rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL result that returns counts for every row where some data exists in a column. I would like to GROUP by results where the grouped values exist in two columns in the table (P1 and P2), and when P1 is NULL, I would like to use P2.

For example, I have an initial query result like the following:

```
+------+------+----------+
|  P1  |  P2  | SomeData |
+------+------+----------+
| Bob  | Mark | data     |
| NULL | Bob  | data     |
| Mark | Tony | data     |
| Mark | Sam  | data     |
| Mark | Bill | data     |
+------+------+----------+
```

And I would like to modify this query to do a grouping so that when P1 is NULL, the new column returns the value from P2. The intended result would look like this:

```
+------+-------+
|  P   | Counts|
+------+-------+
| Bob  |   2   |
| Mark |   3   |
+------+-------+
```

The intended query looks something like this, although, of course, I cannot GROUP BY an aliased column:

```
SELECT
    (CASE WHEN P1 IS NOT NULL THEN P1 ELSE P2 END) AS P,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN SomeData IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Counts
    FROM MyTable
    GROUP BY P
```

Comment: Using coalesce or isnull instead of case makes the code usually easier to read

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for this

```
SELECT
CASE WHEN P1 IS NOT NULL THEN P1 ELSE P2 END AS P,
COUNT(SomeData) AS Counts
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY CASE WHEN P1 IS NOT NULL THEN P1 ELSE P2 END
```

or Case can be simplified by `Coalesce/Isnull` function

```
SELECT
COALESCE(P1,P2) AS P,
COUNT(SomeData) AS Counts
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY COALESCE(P1,P2)
```

1. Just use the entire `CASE` statement instead of `alias`
2. No need to use `Case` statement to `count` the `Not NULL` values. `Count(Colname)` aggregate counts only the `Not NULL` values

Comment: Fantastic - great to understand how to use COALESCE. I also didn't realize you could GROUP BY CASE WHEN... Thanks!